# CV2 if rectangle ist filled then

Tags: opencv

currently im trying a little bit with object detection. Therefor i already programmed a script which detects my object draws rectangles everytime the object gets detected. So the camera pictures gets colored more and more. Now i want that i get a feedback when a specific area is completly colored.

The specific area is also an cv2.rectangle which i added already. I made a little picture to show what i mean.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCAX4.jpg)

The smiliy is my object which hast moved from the right to the left (arrow). The green rectangle ist the area which i want to track. So if inside the green rectangle every spot is inside a red rectangle then the job is done. I made a second drawing which show what i mean.

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9IMS.jpg)

Thank you very much if you have a Idea. :)

Comment: Or easier to say: If a rectangle is completly filled with color (for example red) then i want to get a message. Maybe check every pixel in a fixed area and when every pixel has the same rgb code then its done.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Or maybe make a new black and white image that starts out all white and you draw black rectangles on it. When you don't have any more white pixels, you're done.